# count union of 2 columns in seperate tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an sql query that counts the rows of two columns that reside in different tables joined together by a UNION ALL.

```
SELECT SUM(usernames) AS total 
   FROM 
   ((SELECT count(username) AS usernames 
        FROM table1 
        WHERE columa < '20' AND columnb = 'c' ) 
   UNION ALL 
   (SELECT count(name) AS usernames 
       FROM table2 
       WHERE columna2 < '20' and columnb2 = 'Cat' ))
```

This is not working of course. I ran this statement in phpMyAdmin and it gave me the error....

> Every derived table must have it's own alias.

So rewrote the SQL statement as...

```
SELECT SUM(usernames) AS total 
   FROM 
   ((SELECT count(username) AS usernames 
        FROM table1 a 
        WHERE a.columa < '20' AND a.columnb = 'c' ) 
   UNION ALL 
   (SELECT count(name) AS usernames 
       FROM table2 b 
       WHERE b.columna2 < '20' and b.columnb2 = 'Cat' ))
```

This also gives me the same error...

> Every derived table must have it's own alias.

What am i missing here?

Comment: I suspect that it's "its", not "it's"

Comment: amazing observation. Would really love to give you credit for solving this

Comment: I won't hold my breath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select statements are missing the alias, not table1 and table2 specifically. Try removing parenthesis:

```
SELECT SUM(usernames) AS total 
   FROM 
   (SELECT count(username) AS usernames 
        FROM table1 
        WHERE columa < '20' AND columnb = 'c'  
   UNION 
   SELECT count(name) AS usernames 
       FROM table2 
       WHERE columna2 < '20' and columnb2 = 'Cat' ) a
```

Or creating aliases:

```
SELECT SUM(usernames) AS total 
   FROM 
   ((SELECT count(username) AS usernames 
        FROM table1 
        WHERE columa < '20' AND columnb = 'c' )  a
   UNION ALL 
   (SELECT count(name) AS usernames 
       FROM table2 
       WHERE columna2 < '20' and columnb2 = 'Cat' ) b) c
```

Comment: I think your second query will produce the same error message. The first query will run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the parentheses -- these are fine in most database.  You simply need an alias after the last one:

```
SELECT SUM(usernames) AS total 
FROM ((SELECT count(username) AS usernames 
       FROM table1 a 
       WHERE a.columa < '20' AND a.columnb = 'c' 
      ) UNION ALL 
      (SELECT count(name) AS usernames 
       FROM table2 b 
       WHERE b.columna2 < '20' and b.columnb2 = 'Cat'
      )
     ) t
-------^ voila!
```

It may seem a bit confusing, but subqueries for `union all` do *not* take aliases.  They are needed (in MySQL) for subqueries that behave like tables in a `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
     ( SELECT 1 n) -- this a derived table, with a column alias (n)
     x -- and this is a table alias for said table
```